# IntegrityError: column name1 is not unique

Tags: sql

Every time i run this code i am getting "column name1 is not unique". Why?

```
graph = fb.graph.api(token)
f = graph.get_object(cat = 'single', id = '765898450131958', fields=           ['likes'])
strona = f['id']
liczbalajkow = f['likes']
print liczbalajkow
conn = sqlite3.connect('fb_likes2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Likes (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, name1 TEXT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, likes_count INTEGER, date DATES)''');   
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Likes (name1, likes_count, date)
VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )''', ( strona, liczbalajkow, date.today(), ) );
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably just because it's true and you try to violate the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on name1. Your CREATE TABLE statement defines the field name1 as unique: `name1 TEXT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: explain that this means he tried to insert two rows with the same value for name1 (probably null or the empty string).

Comment: even if i delete UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY and leave only name1 TEXT, it still gives "column name1 is not unique".

Comment: Did you delete the table you created when you first ran it?  Because it'll skip over the table creation since it exists and won't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that you are trying to insert into table duplicate entry for column 'name1'. 
Most probably you are calling this command inside some loop and data received from FB contains the same page name for more than one search result. 
It may also be that you did not delete old database (from previous run).

You can try to display or save to log file values which you are trying to insert into table.

Correct solution would be to create table outside loop.
It should be like:

1. open database connection
2. create table if not exist
3. clear records from table (to avoid duplicates)
4. start loop for FB queries
5. insert record to database
6. close loop
7. close database connection